# Diminuir espaço entre dois JPanel no prototipador do netbeans

Tags: java, swing

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou usando o netbeans 7.4 pra criar uma tela simples. Acontece que nesta tela (frame0 por padrão), eu adicionei dois paineis (JPanel). Um para ser o header e outro para ser o resto da tela.

Escolhi o layout dos paineis como EtchedBorder, e fui arrastando os dois até ajustar na proporção do frame todo.

Mas o problema é que entre o painel superior e o painel inferior fica um espaço fixo. Não consigo diminuir.

Pra tentar ajustar, vou arrastando a borda superior do painel de baixo até encostar na borda inferior do painel de cima. Mas quando solto, o netbeans automaticamente coloca esse espaço.

Alguém sabe me dizer como desativar, ou ajustar este espaço pelo prototipador mesmo? Obrigado.

Comment: Um comentário off: não use Java para desktop.

Comment: @Patrick: qual o motivo para não usar java no desktop?

Comment: Por causa da "compilação" do Java. Engenharia reversa é muito facilitada devido à disso.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é normal, e varia de acordo com o gerenciador de layout que você está utilizando. Caso queira total controle nos bounds de seus componentes Swing, (Netbens) clique com o botão direto em cima do seu JFrame e vai em "Definir Layout" e selecione "Nulo" ou qualquer outro que você conheça (Absolute por exemplo).

Nota: Gerenciadores são bem complexos e tem muita coisa pra falar em só uma resposta. Em suma não é bom usar layout "null" devido incompatibilidade e deformação dos componentes em telas ou sistemas diferentes, Sugiro que estude bem este tópico de Swing para construir um front consistente.

Att.

Answer (score 0):

Tem haver com o layout,  tal como disse o Josué. Para adicionar um layout apropriado: click direito sobre o local onde desejas colocar os JPanels, escolha set layout (como queres header e corpo) podes escolher o Borderô Layout e colocar o JPanel para o "header" na parte Norte e o outro no Centro.